# How to match any string that contains no consecutively repeating letter

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

My regular expression should match if there aren't any consecutive letters that are the same.

for example :

- "ploplir" should match
- "plo**pp**ir" should not match

so I use this regular expression:

```
/([.])\1{1,}/
```

But It does the exact contrary of what I want. How can I make the match work correctly?

Comment: `if (!/(.)\1/.test(s)) { /* Matched */ }`?

Comment: I wanted to do it with the regex expression

Answer (score 2):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/EBBHPB/2)

```
\b(?!\w*(\w)\1)\w+\b
```

```js
var r = /\b(?!\w*(\w)\1)\w+\b/g
var s = "ploplir ploppir"

console.log(s.match(r))
```

---

### Explanation

- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary
- `(?!\w*(\w)\1\w*)` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match

  - `\w*` Match any number of word characters
  - `(\w)` Capture a word character into capture group 1
  - `\1` Match the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capture group
- `\w+` Match one or more word characters
- `\b` Assert position as a word boundary

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to check if there are no consecutive letters in the string:

[`^(?!.*(.)(?=\1)).*$`](https://regex101.com/r/Y8Qk5f/1)

**Explanation**

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- A negative look ahead `(?!`
- Which asserts that following `.*` a character `(.)` is not followed by the same character `(?=\1)` using the group reference `\1`
- Close the negative lookahead
- Match zero or more characters `.*`
- The end of the string